# fit_generator in Keras -- One minibatch at a time

Tags: python, keras

I have a model that operates on a large dataset - not all that large by Big Data standards but significantly more than my home server can hold in memory. As such, I'm using `fit_generator` to load it a chunk at a time, so that it never has to hold more than one minibatch in memory at once.

... At least, that's the *theory*. But when Keras hung at `Epoch 1/10` without even starting the "training" animation and I (eventually) got an Out of Memory exception -- the minibatches are large but I can still hold a couple of them in memory at once without trouble -- I got suspicious and threw in a bunch of testing `print` statements into my generator. Lo and behold, Keras was invoking the generator three or four times before even starting (appearing to start?).

So... what's going on here? Is this normal, or did I implement my generator wrong somehow? How can I get it not to try and load more than one batch at once?

Code follows, in case it helps:

```
def data_gen(directory):
    def epsilon_div(x, y):
        return (x + K.epsilon()) / (y + K.epsilon())

    while(True):
        filelist = os.listdir(directory + "/data")
        order = np.random.permutation(len(filelist))

        for i in order:
            dataf = directory + "/data/" + filelist[i]
            labelf = directory + "/labels/" + filelist[i]

            with open(dataf, 'rb') as f:
                databook = sb.Songbook.FromString(f.read())

            with open(labelf, 'rb') as f:
                labelbook = sb.Songbook.FromString(f.read())

            print('Booked')

            l, _, r, _ = sb_np_extract(databook)
            ll, _, lr, _ = sb_np_extract(labelbook)

            databook = None
            labelbook = None

            print('Extracted')

            l = l.transpose([0, 2, 1])
            r = r.transpose([0, 2, 1])
            ll = ll.transpose([0, 2, 1])
            lr = lr.transpose([0, 2, 1])

            print('Chosen')

            mask_l = epsilon_div(ll, l)
            mask_r = epsilon_div(lr, r)

            print('Done')

            yield [[l, r], [mask_l, mask_r]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you save the filenames in an array then shuffle it. I call the file list with the full path and shuffled `listname_data` and `listname_labels`.

steps = number of files

def generator(steps):

```
i = 1

while True:

     dataf = filelist_data[i]
     labelf = filelist_labels[i]

     ...

     if i == steps:

        i = 1
        c = list(zip(listname_data,listname_data))

        shuffle(c)

        listname_data, listname_data = zip(*c)

     else:

        i +=1

     yield [[l, r], [mask_l, mask_r]]
```

Comment: Calling `next` does indeed run the generator exactly once, and I moved the helper function outside the body of the generator just in case. `fit_generator` still feels the need to run multiple times.

Comment: Yes, `fit_generator` internal code call multiple times the function next(). What I suggest is that you call the next function many times and check that the generator is working correctly.

Comment: It works fine, that's not the problem. The problem is that if you call it more than about four times without discarding old batches, I run out of memory, because my batches are big.

Comment: Maybe I could somehow set it up to block if it can tell there's not enough memory left? I'm not at all sure how to *do* that though...

Comment: I understand what you're saying. The meaning of using a generator is feed the net in batches. Maybe you need to store the dataset in h5py format . Then read the dataset  indexed to avoid store the whole dataset in memory.

Comment: That is roughly speaking what I am doing, yes. I broke up my dataset into smaller batches, which I read one at a time. Each of the files that my generator reads above is a tenth of the full dataset.